# Map discrete columns to the index of their unique values

Tags: python, performance, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe with an int columns:

```
df=pd.DataFrame(data=2*np.random.randint(0,high=10,size=5),columns=['N'])

    N
0   8
1   4
2   8
3  14
4   2
5  18
```

I would like to generate another dataframe as:

```
df2=

    N  ID
0   8  2  
1   4  1
2   8  2
3  14  3
4   2  0
5  18  4
```

where `ID` is the index of the sorted list of unique values in N

I would need a computationally cheap solution as it needs to run on large dataframes and be updated very often.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty simple with [`np.unique`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) with its optional arg `return_inverse` -

```
In [268]: df['ID'] = np.unique(df.N, return_inverse=1)[1]

In [269]: df
Out[269]: 
    N  ID
0   8   2
1   4   1
2   8   2
3  14   3
4   2   0
5  18   4
```

Runtime test (as question said it needed - `a computationally cheap solution`) -

```
# Scale given sample 10,000 times in size and high-limit
In [373]: df=pd.DataFrame(data=2*np.random.randint(0,high=100000,size=50000),columns=['N'])

# @jezrael's soln
In [374]: %timeit df['ID1'] = df['N'].rank(method='dense').sub(1).astype(int)
100 loops, best of 3: 4.74 ms per loop

# Proposed in this post
In [376]: %timeit df['ID2'] = np.unique(df.N, return_inverse=1)[1]
100 loops, best of 3: 3.94 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`rank`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.rank.html) + [`sub`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.sub.html) + [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
df['ID'] = df['N'].rank(method='dense').sub(1).astype(int)
print (df)
    N  ID
0   8   2
1   4   1
2   8   2
3  14   3
4   2   0
5  18   4
```